Pressure measurement using piezometer

When calculating pressure of a flowing liquid,we know that peizometers are used whose one end is open to the atmosphere and the other end is connected to the fluid via a small hole at which we want to measure the pressure. In the pictures attached,below is the cross sectional image of the peizometer attached the the fluid. Now the way,pressure is measured is using the following logic:
$A$ is a point in the section we want to measure pressure and $B$ is a point in the peizometer where both $A$ and $B$ are on the same vertical height. Then pressure is measured as $P_a=P_b$. Now it is said that since the liquid in piezometer is in static condition,$P_b=h\rho g+P_{atm}$ where $h$ is the height of the fluid in piezometer.
But I have some questions regarding this method:
1)Though it appears through common sense that the liquid in the piezometer will be static from real world examples,what is the rigorous proof that the fluid in the peizometer is in fact static whereas the fluid in the pipe is moving?

From Pascals law we know that,pressure at any two points in the same vertical height are equal. Bit that is only for static fluids. But here $A$ is a point where the fluid is moving and $B$ is a point in the piezometer where the fluid is at rest(the issue I mentioned in question $1$ is that why is it at rest though).
So,how can pressures be same for both the points even though they are at same vertical height?

